# How to use android data binding properly

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have the following XML with data binding:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/addvalue"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:digits="0123456789,€"
    android:text="0,00 €"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:onClick="@{() -> fragment.addManualPosition(addvalue.text)}"/>
```

I get the error

```
"data binding error ****msg:if getId is called on an expression, it should have an id: addvalue.text"
```

I can not find anything at all that would help me understand what this error is supposed to mean or how to fix it.

Comment: Do you mind official docs?? https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/

Comment: Why not using a model for your fragment?

Comment: Because transient data in the fragment also needs to be modified (input fields cleared to be ready for the next element) in addition to the change in the model.

Answer (score 44):

I found it myself.
However because there is absolutely nothing written about this error message and it being extremely misleading, I'll keep the question online.

Fix:
The lambda is a perfectly fine **Kotlin** lambda.
However Data Binding seems to generate **Java** code.
So it must not be addvalue.text but addvalue.getText() .

Comment: You save my life,Thanks

Comment: The real messed up thing here is that autocomplete recommends the Kotlin version instead of the Java version.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, the whole topic of passing view arguments to the dataBinding on click function is pretty hard to find and not really popular, would be great if you can change your question's title to something more specific so its easily searchable